# Can't access the If statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have written code for a hangman game which worked normally on Linux (where I wrote it) but now when I compile it on OS X (also using g++) it behaves very weirdly.

I have this function called `getCharacter()` which basically request a single character from the user, then (because I personally found it easier) I saved the character as a type `string` instead of `char`. But when I need to compare if the letter selected exists in the word, I need to extract each character from the chosen word then compare it with the string character typed in by the user. So I do this pretty  awkward conversion of `char` which I got  from the `.at(i)` function of string to the a temp string which then I compare with the chosen letter. If it matches then put the letter into a vector at the `i` position.
It worked grand on Linux, but here weirdly enough, when the user types in a letter even if it is in the chosen word, unless it is the 1st letter, the `if()` statement gets omitted.

So here is my function, I'm still learning so please excuse my lack of professionalism:

```
void Game::getCharacter(){ 

    string character;

    cin >> character;

    while((character.length() > 1) || (checkIfUsed(character))){
        cout << "Not a character or already used, try again:\n";
        cin >> character;
        cout << endl;
    }

    if(RETRIES_LEFT>0){ 
         for(int i = 0; i < DIFFICULTY; i++){
            char TEMP_CHAR = CHOESENWORD.at(i); 
            char *TEMP_CHAR_PTR = &TEMP_CHAR;   
            string TEMP_STRING_LETTER(TEMP_CHAR_PTR);

            if(TEMP_STRING_LETTER == character){

                FRAME.at(i) = character;
                GUESSED+=1;     
            }
        }

        RETRIES_LEFT-= 1;           
        NUM_LETTERS_USED+=1;            
        LETTERS_USED.push_back(character);  
    }   


}
```

Comment: Where does `RETRIES_LEFT` get initialized? Have you put a breakpoint there to check it's value? Is it greater than `0`?

Comment: Does `checkIfUsed` changes `RETRIES_LEFT` in any way?

Comment: Yes its greater than 0. If it is 0 then I skip to the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting straight to the problem:

```
char TEMP_CHAR = CHOESENWORD.at(i);         // grab copy of a char at [i]
char *TEMP_CHAR_PTR = &TEMP_CHAR;           // take the address of the char
string TEMP_STRING_LETTER(TEMP_CHAR_PTR);   // call string(const char* str) 
        // constructor, which is incorrect because strlen(&TEMP_CHAR) will
        // give a pretty random result. this is due to how data is laid out
        // in memory. To sum this up, you're having a buffer overrun issue,
        // where the buffer is TEMP_CHAR (1 byte)
```

This is probably what you want to achieve:

```
if (CHOSENWORD[i] == character[0]) {
```

In either case, there is much to improve in your code, since it's obvious that you're just starting with C/C++. Rest assured, it's actually not that complicated.

How to do it easier? Well, first of all, you can start with only asking for one char:

```
char ch;
std::cin >> ch;     // get a single char
std::cin.sync();    // flush all extra input
```

This should make your code easier to handle.

Comment: @Jorma That was a nice catch. I didn't pay attention to the inner of the `if` statement.

Comment: I'm glad that fixed the issue. I also edited my answer to include a way to grab just a single character from std::cin.

Comment: @JormaRebane: Looks like the OP is starting with C++ since the C language doesn't have extraction operator, `cin`, `cout`, nor `string`.  BTW, there is no language C/C++, as you can see, there are differences.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Since C is a subset of C++, I don't see how strtof doesn't apply - it's faster, more efficient and you have less code. It's great of you to remind me there is no language named "C/C++", I might have not realized that myself... :) Or perhaps one could spell it as "C or C++" instead? ;)

Comment: @JormaRebane:  The C language is not a subset of C++, they are different languages. Another example, the following is valid in C: `struct class std;` and `enum namespace;`.  If C were a subset, those would not be possible.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You seem to be completely missing the point mate. :)

Comment: My point was not about the I/O statements or the string conversion.  My point was the text "you're just starting out with C/C++", and how they are two **different** languages, not subsets.

Comment: Actually, @ThomasMatthews, I should apologize, since it looks like I thought I was posting this reply to a question regarding string tokenizers in C and C++ (hence the seemingly random strtof statement). :) Alas, I should be more observant on which question comment I reply next time.